# infopath 2013 getting the created item date

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I want to get the created date and time of the item. I added a data connection to the list, for getting this value. But, when  I try to assign the **created** value to my textbox , this shows me the lists's created date and time.

So, how can I select the item's created date &time?

Comment: Are you trying to get item's created date&time value from another list?

Comment: no in the same list.

Comment: I don't know how it is going on SharePoint 2013 but why don't u create another date&time column to save item's created date&time? You can assign value of the item's created date with using now() function.